# Expectation inequality of exponential form

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, optimization

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable such that $|X|\leq 1$ and $E[X]=0$. Is it necessarily true that $$E[\exp(X-1000X^2)]\leq 1?$$
If yes, can the constant $1000$ be improved and what is the optimal constant? If no, is it true with a larger constant than $1000$? Or is there a counterexample for arbitrarily large choice of constant?

I tried for a while but could not make any real progress. Maybe there's a simple counterexample where $X$ takes the values $+a$ and $-b$ for some $a,b>0$, but the calculation got annoying. The only affirmative progress I made is a positive answer if $X$ is symmetric, because in this case $E[\exp(X-1000X^2)] = E[\cosh(X)e^{-1000X^2}] \leq E[1] = 1$. In particular $1000$ can be optimally improved to $1/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false in general. You can actually find a counter example using a random variable that only takes two values.

Given some $a\in \mathbb{R}$, let $1>c>0$. Then define a random variable $X$ by
$$
X=\begin{cases}
c & \text{with probability }\frac{1}{c+1}\\
-1 & \text{with probability }\frac{c}{c+1}
\end{cases}
$$
This has expectation $0$ and is bounded in absolute value by 1. However, computing
$$
\mathbb{E}[\exp(X-aX^2)]=\frac{1}{c+1}\exp(c-ac^2)+\frac{c}{c+1}\exp(-1-a)
$$
Think of this expression as a function of $c$. Note that it equals $1$ at $c=0$, and an elementary calculation gives that the derivative at $0$ is $\exp(-1-a)>0$. Hence, since the function is smooth around zero, it follows that there exists some $c>0$ so that the function has a value strictly greater than $1$, yielding the required counterexample.